# Very new to CSS, browser resize causing distortion

Tags: html, css

So I am extremely new to HTML and CSS, and this is the first website I have ever tried to make (for my parents business because they are paying me hahahaha). I just want to get this over with so I never have to do anything like this again :)

So here is the problem, and excuse my English because I do not know how to work this. When the browser gets resized, everything gets "squashed" like this:
[Before Resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/234GU.jpg)
then
[After Resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ufd.jpg)

Now again this is the first and last time I'm doing this so don't judge my art/programming.
In the HTML documents I simply put the images/ text in, and in the Main.css I did the following for pretty much everything:

```
{position:absolute;
left: 50.5%;
top: 115px;
font-size: 40px;
color:aliceblue;
font-family:Courier New;
width: 16%;}


{Position:absolute;
left: 15.6%;
top: 300px;
width: 84%;}
```

Now I just want a fixed page. I tried using Pixels instead of percents, and it looked great on my 1080p monitor, but it did not look great on the 720p one because I have to scroll left to see it all. I know Im an idiot, but please help me?

Comment: A good read http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Comment: [Responsive design](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [responsive design](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp). For that either you can use twitter [bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) or [custom media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height: auto` to your `img` selectors, like this:

```
img.logo {
   position:absolute;
   left: 15.6%;
   top: 300px;
   width: 84%; 
   height: auto;
}
```

But you will soon get more similar situations with content not rendering properly on different screens, so you really should use something like Bootstrap - this will save a lot of your time in the future.
Try using [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) for navigation and [jumbotrone](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) with background image with bees for page title.

Comment: Auto height seems to stretch out the page vertically. should I use it on all img selectors?

Comment: Using `height: auto` on images like `img { height: auto; ... }` should make image to keep their aspect ratio with any width. Maybe it solves your problem now, but, sooner or later, you will come up with desision to use some responsive framework, so I recommend you to start learning it now, it is not that hard. However, you should first be familiar with html and css, so I highly recommend you to take the corresponding tutorial on, for example, w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the same image in different screen resolution is tricky, 
There are various possibilities.

Short article, using the
[Picture tag](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/)

Or Try this complete [free online course, Udacity responsive images](https://www.udacity.com/course/responsive-images--ud882)

Best